# An unnecessary "for all"

Tags: logic, notation

One way to write the symmetry condition in a relation $\sim$ on a set $A$ is as follows:

- i. For all $a \in A$ and for all $b \in A$, if $a \sim b$, then $b  \sim a$.

In practice this is sometimes shortened as:

- ii. For all $a, b \in A$, if $a \sim b$, then $b  \sim a$.

My question is whether it is correct to omit the "for all" in those sentences... I believe that it is not that uncommon to see the following variant of i (or ii) in the literature:

- iii. If $a, b \in A$ and $a \sim b$, then $b \sim a$.

Is iii regarded as some sort of abuse of language by some authors?

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Yes; in mathematical jargon, an universal quantifier is often implicit. When we assert that the identity $(x^2-y^2)=(x-y)(x+y)$ holds we write it omitting the universal quantifiers.

Comment: I think it is improper to write $a,b\in A$ as part of the antecedent of the conditional statement.

Comment: Andre Chin: Are you saying that both i and ii are incorrect?

Comment: No; the antecedent of a conditional statement comes immediately after _if_ and before _then_.

Comment: So, you are saying that both i and ii are correct and that iii is utterly incorrect, right?

Comment: @Jamai-Con I guess he's saying that usually you say: If $a\sim b$ for $a,b \in A$, then $b\sim a$ (to me it seems all three are correct ways to say it)

Comment: @LeoHö: Are you saying that the right way to write i is "If $a \sim b$ for all $a \in A$ and $b \in A$, then $b \sim a$"?

Comment: Statement iii is fine. As Mauro said, it means "for all $a$ and $b$, if $a,b\in A$ and $a\sim b$ then $b\sim a$, which is what you wanted. The alternative "if $a\sim b$ for all $a,b\in A$ then $b\sim a$" is wrong, because it makes the "for all" part apply only to the antecedent rather than the whole implication.